# Polynomial and complex numbers.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $ f (x) $ be a polynomial with real coefficients.  Show that the remainder of dividing $ f (x) $ by $ x² + 2x + 2 $ is given by $$ r (x) = \alpha x + \beta $$ where $ \alpha = \Im(f (1 + i  )) $ y $ \beta = \Re (f (1 + i)) - \Im (f (i + 1)) $.

I assumed that the remainder of $ f (x) $ when dividing by $ x ^ 2 + 2x + 2 $ is $ r (x) = \alpha x + \beta $.  And using the roots of $ x ^ 2 + 2x + 2 $ I am trying to find linear equations in which the unknowns would have to be $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $.  I don't know how to continue to find those Equations.

Comment: Well $f(1+i)=0+\alpha (1+i)  +\beta$  where $\alpha,\beta$ are real. [Ps trivial typo, you wrote "y" and meant "and".]

Comment: The roots of $x ^ 2 + 2x + 2$ would help, indeed, but $1+i$ is not one of them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the core of your problem is to relate $f(1+i)$, $f(-1-i)$ and $f(-1+i)$.

My attempt:

$$f(1+i)$$
$$f(-1-i) = f(-(1+i))$$
$$f(-1+i) = f(-(1+i)^*)$$

It's important to note that

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
(1+i)^1 = (1+i)\\
(1+i)^2 = (2i)\\
(1+i)^3 = -2+2i=-2(1-i)=-2(1+i)^*\\
(1+i)^4 = (-4)\\
(1+i)^5 = -4-4i=-4(1+i)\\
(1+i)^6 = -8i=(2i)^3\\
(1+i)^7 = 8-8i=8(1-i)=8(1+i)^*\\
(1+i)^8 = 16=(-4)^2\\
(1+i)^9 = 16+16i=16(1+i)\\
(1+i)^{10} = 32i=(2i)^5\\
(1+i)^{11} = -32+32i=-32(1-i)=-32(1+i)^*\\
(1+i)^{12} = -64=(-4)^3\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
(1+i)^n = (-1)^{\frac{n+7}{4}}(+2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1+i) \text{ for } n = 1,5,9,...\\
(1+i)^n = (-1)^{\frac{n+6}{4}}(+2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\,i \text{ for } n = 2,6,10,...\\
(1+i)^n = (-1)^{\frac{n+1}{4}}(+2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1+i)^* \text{ for } n = 3,7,11,...\\
(1+i)^n = (-2)^{\frac{n}{2}} \text{ for } n = 4,8,12,...\\
\end{array}
$$

We know that $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = a_0 + \sum_{n=1,5,9,...} a_n \, x^n + \sum_{n=2,6,10,...} a_n \, x^n + \sum_{n=3,7,11,...} a_n \, x^n + \sum_{n=4,8,12,...} a_n \, x^n
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f(-x) & = a_0 - \sum_{n=1,5,9,...} a_n \, x^n + \sum_{n=2,6,10,...} a_n \, x^n - \sum_{n=3,7,11,...} a_n \, x^n + \sum_{n=4,8,12,...} a_n \, x^n
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f(-x^*) = [f(-x)]^* & = a_0 - \sum_{n=1,5,9,...} a_n \, (x^n)^* + \sum_{n=2,6,10,...} a_n \, (x^n)^* - \sum_{n=3,7,11,...} a_n \, (x^n)^* + \sum_{n=4,8,12,...} a_n \, (x^n)^*
\end{align}
$$

Maybe there is sufficient information now.